# Declare a variable when running the script bash

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

How to declare the variable content when running the script?

I know that is possible to use $1 $2 $3 to set a variable when running the script `./script.sh this is sparta`, but I did not found a way to set explicit.

Like
`./script.sh URL=www.google.com COMMAND=wget`

This is possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you invoke it with the variable declarations *before* the command, bash will put those variables in the environment created for that command. After the command, the variables will no longer exist in the current shell:

```
$ cat ./script.sh
#!/bin/sh
echo URL is $URL
echo COMMAND is $COMMAND
$ ./script.sh URL=www.google.com COMMAND=wget
URL is
COMMAND is
$ URL=www.google.com COMMAND=wget ./script.sh
URL is www.google.com
COMMAND is wget
$ echo $URL,$COMMAND
,
```

Reference: http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Simple-Command-Expansion